# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'String?' operands

Tags: swift, string

My code doesn't work. It shows problems like this:

```swift
let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

let password = alphabet.randomElement() + alphabet.randomElement()
print(password)
```

I am a beginner of Swift and I don't know how to fix it. I am searching on the Internet and I can't find anything like that.

Comment: What if you tried creating two string variables with the output of alphabet.randomElement() and then concatenating those two vars together?

Answer (score 1):

As a beginning Swift developer, read up on Optionals. They will give you fits until you understand them. I suggest downloading and reading Apple's Swift book for their Books platform (formerly known as iBooks.) You can read their e-books on your Mac or on an iPad. (I don't recommend it on an iPhone though. The screen is too small.)

Now, to your question:

The function `randomElement()` returns an Optional. That's because the array could be empty.

Think of an optional like a box that may be empty or it may contain an object. Optionals can be typed, so an Integer Optional (`Int?`) is a box that either contains an integer or nothing (nil)

You have to "unwrap" an optional to see what's in it.

There are various ways to do that. For your case, I would recommend using the "nil coalescing operator", `??`. That lets you provide a placeholder value to use if the Optional contains nil.

Consider this code:

```
var foo: String? = "bar"
let newFoo = foo ?? "nil"
```

The expression `foo ?? "nil"` will try to unwrap foo. If it contains a string, you get the string. If it contains nil, it returns the value you provide after the `??` - in this case, the **String** "nil".

Using that in your code, it would look like this:

```
let password = alphabet.randomElement() ?? "" + alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
```

So you provide a placeholder empty string for both calls to `randomElement()`. It should never be nil, but if it is, you just get an empty string.

There is also something called the "force unwrap" operator, `!`. I would avoid that like the plague until you really, really, **REALLY** know what you are doing. (And then you should still try to avoid it.) I call it the "crash if nil" operator, because that's what it does. If the optional you are unwrapping contains nil, your program crashes.

Then there are other things like optional binding (`if let`), `guard`, and various other ways of handling Optionals that you should learn about and get familiar with.

Comment: I disagree with *still try to avoid it.* `let password = alphabet.isEmpty ? "" : alphabet.randomElement()! + alphabet.randomElement()!` is a 100% reliable reasonable code. And there are other APIs where force unwrapping is not that evil for example `let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate`.

Comment: @vadian IDK how approachable this would be to newbs, but I'd prefer `let password = alphabet.map { $0.randomElement() + $0.randomElement() } ?? ""`

Comment: Another solution that generates a compilation error...

Comment: @vadian, For beginning Swift developers, force-unwrapping is death. I will agree that there are cases where you can be certain the optional being unwrapped isn't nil. Like Alexander I think we tend to overuse the trinary operator and it makes for less readable code.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1:

in most cases using "!" means bad code. But in THIS exact case it is ok to use here because of "alphabet" array for sure is not empty:

```
let password = alphabet.randomElement()! + alphabet.randomElement()!
print(password)
```

## Solution 2:

But better codestyle is to use sth like this:

```
guard let rnd1 = alphabet.randomElement(),
      let rnd2 = alphabet.randomElement()
else { return } // here must be your error handling

let password = "\(rnd1)\(rnd2)"

print(password)
```

Comment: What is `alpabet` in your solution? Both examples gives me compilation error about using `+` with `Character`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the same as in authors code :) In authors code it is absent in the question. And I believe there is array with alphabet symbols  just like written in name of variable :) And by the way, strange that you ask this only me, but didn't ask an author and other people that leave answers here :)

Comment: I did ask OP and I was on my way asking the others but one thing at a time.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson fixed `+` error :)

Answer (score -1):

`alphabet.randomElement()` returns an Optional hence one needs to unwrap it first.

```swift
if let randElement = alphabet.randomElement( ) as? String {
   print (randElement + randElement)
}
```

Comment: here is single random element, code doesn't work as author expected))